# How can I change javaCC adder.jj to receive a String instead of a stream from command prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, io, javacc

I created `adder.jj` file following [this](https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf) tutorial (till page 13, just before it starts with the calculator example), to create an adder, which works great for obtaining the result of numbers and plus sign in a syntactically correct way (e.g. "4+3   +7" returns 14, while "4++3" gives an error), those numbers and + signs come from a text file (this is explained in a bit).
The code I use to generate the needed classes to do what is explained before.

```
options
{
    STATIC = false ;
}
PARSER_BEGIN(Adder)
    class Adder
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        throws ParseException, TokenMgrError, NumberFormatException 
        {
            Adder parser = new Adder (System.in) ;
            int val = parser.Start() ;
            System.out.println(val) ;
        }
    }
PARSER_END(Adder)

SKIP : { " " }
SKIP : { "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n" }
TOKEN : { < PLUS :"+"> }
TOKEN : { < NUMBER : (["0"-"9"])+ > }

int Start() throws NumberFormatException :
{
    int i ;
    int value ;
}
{
    value = Primary()
    (
        <PLUS>
        i = Primary()
        { value += i ; }
    )*
    { return value ; }
}

int Primary() throws NumberFormatException :
{
    Token t ;
}
{
    t=<NUMBER>
    { return Integer.parseInt( t.image ) ; }
}
```

The classes are generated with

```
javacc adder.jj
```

Then I compile the generated classes with

```
javac *.java
```

And finally

```
java Adder < ex1.txt
```

Gives the right output if the content of `ex1.txt` has the format I explained before.

How can I change this code to receive a String so I can actually use it in my project instead of the stream from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Adder parser = new Adder (System.in) ;
```

with

```
Reader reader = new StringReader( someString ) ;
Adder parser = new Adder( reader ) ;
```

Comment: I tried that, it says the following

`Adder.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                        Reader reader = new StringReader("4+2+  88") ;
                        ^
  symbol:   class Reader
  location: class Adder
Adder.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                        Reader reader = new StringReader("4+2+  88") ;
                                            ^
  symbol:   class StringReader
  location: class Adder
2 errors`

Also eclipse says doesn't recognize StringReader even after I import java.io.reader

Comment: Sorry I had to import 
`import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;`
in the Adder.java generated class
And it works! thanks a lot, man... now I just have to change it to work with a static method different than main!